# pandas.read_excel() na_values not working correctly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

As title states, after [reviewing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

I am reading an .xlsx file, with a column 'HOUR' which has many values, when an instance has value 99, i want to convert to None

I have tried the na_values param with different values:

```
na_values = ['99'] 
na_values = [r'99']
na_values = 99
...
```

To then read the excel like this:

```
accidents = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name= 'datos', na_values=[99])
```

but it doesn't seem to work, when i do:

```
np.sum(accidents['HOUR'] == 99)
```

I get a value > than 0 (which means the instances with value = 99 have not been transformed to None/NaN)

I have also read that i should include the option

```
keep_default_na=False
```

but to no avail.

The values of the 'HOUR' column are:

```
accidents['HOUR'].unique()
array([ 8, 15,  9, 14, 11,  0, 13, 20,  3, 19, 17,  7, 22, 21, 16,  6, 23,
   18, 10, 12,  1, 99,  4,  5,  2, 24], dtype=int64)
```

I have updated my pandas version to 1.5.1 and it still doesn't work, any ideas why?

.xls file can be found in: http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Fields.asp?Table_ID=1158

Thank you

Comment: add the values of the HOUR column to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `replace` method on the dataframe after reading the excel file:

```
df.replace(99, np.nan)
```

If you want to replace values for only specific column like Hour:

```
df['HOUR'].replace(99, np.nan)
```

**Update:**

I think you want to know why `read_excel()` method isn't working with the na values you provided, if you check the documentation for the method:

> **na_values : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None** Additional
> strings to recognize as NA/NaN.

It only accept strings in the `na_values` paramater, so you need to pass it as string '99' in order to work in your case.

For some reasons it's not working for `integer` na_values in excel sheets. according to docs `read_excel` method column types are inferred but can be explicitly specified. maybe it doesn't set `HOUR` col type correctly so the `na_values` not working.
I found a work around by specifying column data type in the method explicitly and it worked perfectly:

```
accidents = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name= 'datos', dtype={'HOUR': str}, na_values=['99'])

accidents = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name= 'datos', dtype={'HOUR': str}, na_values=[99])
```

Comment: Okay, but do you know why it might not be working?

Also, how would yo go about replacing different values based on cols?

Take a dict for example: 

missing_values_dict = {
  "WEEKDAY": '9',
  "HOUR": '99',
}

Would this be possible? 

Thank yoou!

Comment: If you are reading the excel sheet as dataframe. it should work perfectly. check if it takes the names of the columns correctly when reading excel file. Also you can replace values based on cols check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the column names are taken in perfectly, thank you for your answer, but i should be able to do what i intend with the param na_values right?

Comment: Yes, it will exclude `NaN` values from result set.
If the answer solve your problem mark it as accepted.

Comment: But this doesn't solve my question, which is why this would not work, I appreciate your answer, and it is one of many ways of changing certain values to NaN but it is not what I asked, which is why the param na_values in the function pd.read_excel() is not working as expected

Comment: @JuanPañosBasterra check my updated answer. I think i understand what you want.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but if you check the values I have tried with, ['99'] is already tried, and still doesn't work, this is why I posted the question, it should work according to doc but doesn't...

Comment: Very strange did you try it with `na_values = [99]` and doesn't also work.

Comment: Can you send me link to the file so I can test on it.

Comment: Yes, i tried na_values = [99] and still not working, the database is something similar to: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents but in .xls file, which might have something to do with it...

Comment: @JuanPañosBasterra Bro I found work around for your problem. thanks for providing dataset. check my updated answer it should work for you now.

Comment: [Oghli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5169186/oghli) Thanks bro, nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, an update.

I still have not figured out why the read_excel() function is not working as expected

If anyone has this problem, i suggest transforming .xls/.xlsx file to .csv and changing the read function like this:

```
accidents = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet = 0, na_values = missing_values_dict, keep_default_na=False)

accidents = pd.read_csv(filename , sep = ';', na_values= missing_values_dict, keep_default_na=False)
```

with missing_values_dict something like:

```
missing_values_dict = {
  'WEEKDAY': '9',
  'HOUR': '99'
}
```

any questions let me know!